# JAVA tomcat 7 localhost is currently unable to handle this request. HTTP ERROR 500

Tags: java, spring, gradle, tomcat7

I am running Spring project on **tomcat 7**
I got above response in on browser on project URL

no logs in tomcat **Catalina.out** 
and 
tomcat localhost log as follows

```
Aug 09, 2018 4:30:00 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet errorServlet threw exception
javax.servlet.ServletException: Could not resolve view with name 'error/general/content' in servlet with name 'errorServlet'
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1183)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:986)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:933)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:851)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:953)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:844)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:620)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:829)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:748)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:488)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:411)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:338)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.custom(StandardHostValve.java:473)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.status(StandardHostValve.java:342)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:207)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:421)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1070)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:611)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:314)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: Please include more details. This error may be `error/general/content` there no jsp file corresponding to this url.

Comment: There  no such gsp.This error show for all url for my application

Comment: Please include your spring configuration too. Without jsp how your system works? Is it webservices?